# How can I get the version argument of a find_package() call in my find module script?

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I have custom Find.cmake. Is it possible to retrieve `version`, passed to the `find_package()` call, inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested version can be extracted via `<PackageName>_FIND_VERSION` variable, where `<PackageName>` substitution denotes the package name (the first parameter of the `find_package`):

```cmake
if(Foo_FIND_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.4)
  # search for the old variant of the package Foo
else()
  # search for the new variant of the package Foo
endif()
```

There are also other variables, which describes the version request in more details. See [documentation for find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#package-file-interface-variables).

---

Note, that if your Find script searches the **only instance** of the package, then you don't need to explicitly check the requested version: just extract version of the package which you have found, and pass it via VERSION_VAR parameter of [find_package_handle_standard_args](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html#command:find_package_handle_standard_args) helper. That helper will automatically checks whether requested version is compatible with the one which has been found.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Somehow missed `<PackageName>_FIND_*` variables.